# How to keep Memory View open in CLion?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I open the Memory View by pressing Ctrl+Enter (or rightclick and "View in Memory") on an active variable during debugging from the watches window, it closes after I re-run the program or stop it.

I've tried pinning the tab and searching through the settings but to no avail.

Is there any way to keep it open even after I stop/re-run the debug of the code? Visual Studio allows this.

Comment: Currently, there's no way to keep it, unfortunately. We plan to make it stay open as long as the corresponding debug tool window is there. May I ask you what you exact use case is? Do you compare memory dumps across multiple runs or smth?

Comment: I'm working on an assignment to program something that simulates how malloc works. I'm trying to find where the code crashes so I'm looking through the memory, often needing to stop the program to make modifications the code before re-running again